# Git - update local branches

Tags: git

i'm trying to understand the differences between `git remote prune origin` and `git remote update origin --prune`?
Are both of them updates ALL local branches according to remote? adds/removes local branches according to remote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git remote update origin --prune` updates (fetches) and then prunes stale refs.

`git remote prune origin` *just* prunes stale refs.

Answer (score 3):

`git remote update --prune` fetches updates for your remote tracking branches, and also deletes (prunes) any which no longer exist on the remote.

`git remote prune` does not fetch updates, it only prunes.

Neither touch local branches, though they may prune tags.

See [Pruning in git-fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_pruning) for more.